# haskell function for si

Tags: function, haskell, figure, chess

I am trying to write a function `render` by using `toPosition` with

```
render :: Dimensie -> Figure a -> [[a]]
```

But I can't figure out how. Could you propose a way to do this?

```
type Figure a = Pos -> a

type Pos = (Double, Double) -- (x, y)

chessboard :: Figure Bool
chessboard (x, y) = even (round x) == even (round y)

type Dimensie = (Int, Int)

render :: Dimensie -> Figure a -> [[a]] 
render  = undefined

toPosition :: Dimensie → (Int, Int) → Pos
toPosition d (x, y) = (fromIntegral x ∗ 2 / b − 1, 1 − fromIntegral y ∗ 2 / h)
        where
           b = fromIntegral (fst d − 1)
           h = fromIntegral (snd d − 1)
```

And when I call it with

```
 Figure> render (3,3) chessboard
```

it should give

```
[[True,False,True],[False,True,False],[True,False,True]]
```

And then I want to follow this up by writing a function that gives a certain character for a certain boolean value. It should display for example `@` for `True` and `.` for `False`

```
boolChar :: Bool -> Char
boolChar = undefined
```

But how do I write this?
I don't get how to get a `[[Bool]]` out of `[[a]]` at the `render` function, it keeps telling me that it `couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Bool’` and that `‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by the type signature for:` and then it tells which line it went wrong.
So what do I write for `render d (x,y) c = ....` to get it to display the asked outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few hints:

- Write a function to generate a table of `Pos` with all the coordinates, i.e. a `[[Pos]]` like this

  ```
  generateTable (i,j) = [[(1,1),(1,2),...,(1,j)], ..., [(i,1),...,(i,j)]]
  ```

  - To solve this you might want to write an auxiliary function `generateRow x j = [(x,1),...,(x,j)]` first, and then use it to generate each row
  - You can use recursion, or you might also use a (possibly nested) list comprehension. There are many options.
- Once you have your `table :: [[Pos]]` you can `map (map figure) table` to get the wanted `[[a]]`.

  - Alternatively, you can use the `figure` function sooner, and avoid to generate the pairs in the first place.